# using await within function of backend api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I have the code below:

**service.js**

```
module.exports = {
  getUser
};
async function getUser({ data }) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const id = data["id"];
  
    const doc = await db.collection('users').where('id', '==', id).get();

    if (!doc.exists) {
      resolve('No such document!');
    } else {
      resolve(doc.data());
    }

  });

}
```

**controller.js**

```
async function getUser(req, res, next) {
  userService.getUser({ data: req.body }).then(function (val) {
    res.json(val);
  });
}
```

This throws an error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`. How can I retrieve the data from the await in an effective manner?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `await` only inside `async` function.

```js
function dummy() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(20)
    }, 300)
  })
}

let val = new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
  let v = await dummy()
  resolve(v)
})


val.then(value => console.log(value))
```